# Streaming Overlapped Videos over RTP

Tags: video, video-streaming, gstreamer, video-processing

I am trying to implement a system that takes live camera stream, overlays some text and symbols (using Alpha-Channel transparency); and transmits it over RTP/UDP, as a single video (from one port). Both host and client systems have [i.MX6QP](http://www.nxp.com/products/microcontrollers-and-processors/arm-based-processors-and-mcus/i.mx-applications-processors/i.mx-6-processors/i.mx-6quadplus-processor-quad-core-high-performance-advanced-3d-graphics-hd-video-advanced-multimedia-arm-cortex-a9-core:i.MX6QP) on. For now, I am trying to figure out the GStreamer and pipeline system with gst-launch, and only using test patterns as video sources.

Here is a simplified diagram to show what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

I have seen the [videomixer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-videomixer.html) plugin, but from what I understand, it is only used for **overlaying and playing videos**, not for creating 'transmittable' video streams. (I can use it with xvimagesink, but I couldn't achieve to implement the pipeline with udpsink. And I couldn't find a workaround for it.)

I haven't been able to find right tools/methods to implement the system described above. Am I right about the videomixer plugin? If so, what do you suggest me to do? Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the nature of your triangle and circle videos: RAW, compressed? (I guess it's RAW for now since you're using `videotestsrc`)

Comment: You're right, they are RAW for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're processing stream on I.MX6, you should take a look at the `imxg2dcompositor` plugin in [gstreamer-imx](https://github.com/Freescale/gstreamer-imx)

```
gst-inspect-1.0 imxg2dcompositor
```

From their example, can you try something like:

```
gst-launch-1.0   \
  imxg2dcompositor name=c background-color=0x223344 \
      sink_0::xpos=0 sink_0::ypos=90 sink_0::width=160 sink_0::height=110 sink_0::zorder=55 sink_0::fill_color=0xff00ff00 sink_0::alpha=0.39 sink_0::rotation=0 \
      sink_1::xpos=0 sink_1::ypos=20 sink_1::width=620 sink_1::height=380 sink_1::fill_color=0x44441133 ! \
    queue2 ! "video/x-raw, width=800, height=600" ! imxipuvideotransform ! imxvpuenc_h264 ! rtph264pay ! udpsink \
  videotestsrc pattern=0 ! "video/x-raw, framerate=30/1" ! c.sink_0 \
  videotestsrc pattern=18 ! "video/x-raw, framerate=30/1" ! c.sink_1
```

I'll advise you not to miss the video encoding part which is essential when trying to setup video streaming applications (H.264 encoding plugin is `imxvpuenc_h264`). This encoding step is followed by a specific RTP pay-loader.

Comment: Ok, it is easier to understand with your diagram :)

Comment: Sorry I had no access to the boards last week, so I have just tried your pipeline. It gives error, saying "WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not link queue2-0 to imxvpuh264enc0". Adding imxipuvideotransform element before the encoder solves this issue. Thank you so much for your help!